# INSERT SQL records from one database to a second (where 2nd has an additional column)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I'd like to insert select records from Table A --> Table B (in this example case, different "databases" == different tables to not worry about `ATTACH`), where `Table A` has less columns than `Table B`. The additional `B_Table` column (`col3`) should also be populated.

### I've tried this sequence in raw-SQL (through SQLAlch.):

1.) `INSERT`ing `A_Table` into Table B using an engine.connect().execute(**text**)

```
text("INSERT INTO B_Table (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM A_Table")
```

2.) `UPDATE`ing `B_Table` w/ `col3` info with an engine.connect()ion (all newly inserted records are populated/updated w/ the same identifier, `NewInfo`)

```
text("UPDATE B_Table SET col3 = NewInfo WHERE B_Table.ID >= %s" % (starting_ID#_of_INSERT'd_records))
```

### More efficient alternative?

But this is incredibly inefficient. It takes 4x longer to `UPDATE` a single column than to `INSERT`. This seems like it should be a fraction of the `INSERT` time. I'd like to reduce the total time to ~just the insertion time.

What's a better way to copy data from one table to another w/out `INSERT`ing followed by an `UPDATE`? I was considering a:

1.) SQLAlchemy `session.query(A_Table)`, but wasn't sure how to then edit that object (for `col3`) and then insert that updated object w/out loading all the `A_Table` queried info into RAM (which I understand raw-SQL's `INSERT` does not do).

Comment: Is NewInfo a string literal or an identifier?

Comment: @forpas Sorry, NewInfo is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'NewInfo'` as a string literal in the `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO B_Table (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2, 'NewInfo' 
FROM A_Table;
```